# Use generated java sdk for web portal?

Tags: iot, kaa

I am creating a web portal that controls the devices (like switching it on/off), visualize the data sent by those devices(endpoints). I have generated a java sdk. Do i use that sdk in my web portal or is it just for a device that sends telemetry data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is desirable to use generated sdk only for device that sends telemetry data.
There is no point in attaching sdk to your web application, as far as this part of the system doesn't treated as endpoint. It is bad practice to include endpoint sdk into the places, where lion's share of functionality would be ignored.